# Selecting one out of many strings with concatenation in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have to match the following URLs by writing a query in `Amazon Redshift`:

```
<some url>/www.abc.com/a/<more url>
<some url>/www.abc.com/b/<more url>
<some url>/www.abc.com/c/<more url>
<some url>/www.abc.com/d/<more url>
```

Here, obviously the "/www.abc.com/" is constant, but the text after '/' can change.  It can take one of the many values that I have a list of (a,b,c,d in this case). How do I match this part that comes immediately after "/www.abc.com/"?

I can think of the following:

```
select text,
       case 
           when text ilike '%/www.abc.com/' || <what should go here?> || '/%' then 'URLType1'
           when <some other condition> then 'URLType2'
       end as URLType
from table
```

I have to maintain the `CASE` structure.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe options are:

1) put the list of values into a subquery and then join to this list like this:

```
with
value_list as (
    select 'a' as val union select 'b' union select 'c' union select 'd'
)
select text
from table
join value_list
on text ilike '%/www.abc.com/' || val || '/%'
```

2) use OR:

```
select text,
   case 
        when text ilike '%/www.abc.com/a/%' 
        or text ilike '%/www.abc.com/b/%' 
        or text ilike '%/www.abc.com/c/%' 
        or text ilike '%/www.abc.com/d/%' 
        then 'URLType1'
        when <some other condition> 
        then 'URLType2'
   end as URLType
```

from table

3) Write a Python UDF that takes the url and the list and returns true or false like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multi_ilike(str varchar(max),arr varchar(max))
RETURNS boolean
STABLE AS $$
    if str==None or arr==None:
        return None
    arr = arr.split(',')
    str = str.lower()
    for i in arr:
        if i.lower() in str:
            return True
    return False
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;

select multi_ilike('<some url>/www.abc.com/a/<more url>','/www.abc.com/a/,/www.abc.com/b/,/www.abc.com/c/,/www.abc.com/d/'); -- returns true
select multi_ilike('<some url>/www.abc.com/F/<more url>','/www.abc.com/a/,/www.abc.com/b/,/www.abc.com/c/,/www.abc.com/d/'); -- returns false
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But for my case, I cannot join the table with `value_list`. I have to match it as part of a single statement coz this is a derived table which is a resultant of a pretty big query itself. I am matching other URLs as part of this query too, so this particular bit will form a small part of a big `CASE` condition.

Comment: got it. Updating